# Saving sip registration/unregistration in Asterisk into MySQL

Tags: mysql, asterisk, registration

How can I save sip accounts registration/unregistration into MySQL?

I have only one idea at the moment ...

Now I'm trying to parse asterisk's full log:

```
cat /var/log/asterisk/full | grep "egistered SIP " | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$6,$7,$8}' | sort -t" " -k2 -n
```

and saving information into table:

```
sip_registrations (id, sip, datetime, event[1 - registration; 2 - unregistration] )
```

Is there any easier way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sip realtime(peers from db) and set it to update state of peer.

You can listen AMI interface for event.

You can read logs and parse.